# Circle 2.0 - angular 5 build fails only when cache enabled

Tags: angular, circleci

I have a `Circle CI 2.0` project where I'm building an `Angular 5` application.

Previously I enabled caching (restore + save) and the was something wrong with the configuration (probably `--preserveSymlinks true` missing) so I fixed it.

Disabling the cache, and re-deploying with this new configuration works. The original error was:

> Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

Now, if I keep CircleCI 2.0 cache **disabled**, it works.
However, If I deploy (with cached disabled) and then re-enable the cache (since in theory the new cache should replace the one cached with wrong configuration) I get that error again **as the previous cache was still used, leading to the error which caused the build to break on the first place**.

My `circleci 2.0 config` follows:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10-browsers
        environment:
           CHROME_BIN: "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: |
          head -n -6 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome | sudo tee /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-updated
          echo 'exec -a "$0" /opt/google/chrome/chrome --no-sandbox "$@"' | sudo tee -a /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-updated
          sudo mv /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-updated /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
          sudo chmod 775 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
          ls -lah /usr/bin/google-chrome && ls -lah /etc/alternatives/google-chrome && ls -lah /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable && ls -lah /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

      # Download and cache dependencies
      # TODO: fix cache issue causing Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
#      - restore_cache:
#          keys:
#          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
#          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
#          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      ######
      # test
      ######
#      - run:
#          name: angular-test
#          command: ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results.xml

      ######
      # build
      ######
      - run: npm run ng -- build --prod --aot --no-progress --preserveSymlinks true
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the only way to properly `reset the cache` (since deploying **without** cache, and then re-deploying with cache, **doesn't** seem to work) is to change the `cache ID`.

For example:

> Replace **all** `v1-dependencies` strings with `some-other-name`